# Using sheet codename in sorting code

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to write all my code using codenames to prevent errors if a name gets changed and to stop activating/selecting sheets.  This was going well until I got to the sort code where I thought the following would select `Sheet2`

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
  "A2:A" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
  xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range( _
  "J2:J" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
  xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2).Sort
  .SetRange Range("A1:J" & LastRow)
  .Header = xlYes
  .MatchCase = False
  .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
  .SortMethod = xlPinYin
  .Apply
End With
```

It does in fact work on Sheet2, but I found out after adding a new sheet that it is counting sheets based on their position in the document (tabs at the bottom).

Trying to replace any of those lines with something like `ActiveWorkbook.Sheet2.Sort.SortFields.Clear` gives me error "438 - Object doesn't support this property or method".

The only way I have been able to get this to work is to replace it with `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet2.Name).Sort.SortFields.Clear`.  It seems to me that maybe I am missing something here but I am having trouble searching for anything related to codename and sorting.

Comment: is the code in the same workbook?  To quote OzGrid, "The only times you cannot use a sheets CodeName is when you reference a Sheet that is in a different Workbook to the one that the code resides."  http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-vba-sheet-names.htm

Comment: Yes they are in the same workbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assign the sheet to a variable using the Code Name:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheet2
```

Then you would call each line with:

```
ws.Sort...
```

Comment: I was able to skip doing that and just go with `Sheet2.Sort.SortFields.Clear` but is there any way to reference the workbook?  I tried `ThisWorkbook.Sheet2` but that gave me an error as well.

Comment: no this is one of those times you will want to do something like. `ThisWorkbook.Activate` before the `Set ws = Sheet2` to ensure that the correct code name is selected.

Comment: Confused as to why you need to 'reference the workbook'?? If you have working code with `Sheet2.Sort.SortFields.Clear`, then why do you want to try and add the workbook object into the equation?#

Comment: If another workbook is selected while the code is running, would it not sort the active selected workbook instead of the intended one unless I define which workbook?

Comment: No If you put the activate line immediately above the set line, the chance of the workbook being shifted in that millionth of a second is nearly impossible.  And once the variable is set the workbook reference is also set and will not change regardless as what is made active after.  @tjb1

Answer (score 0):

Use the Worksheet name rather than its index as in:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
```

This works as long as the sheet name doesn't change.

Comment: I'm avoiding using the actual sheet name to prevent errors if/when it gets changed.

Comment: Is it the active worksheet always when the script runs? If it is then you can just assign a worksheet variable and then just reference it. Something like `Dim ws as worksheet; Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet`. Then just reference `ws` from then onwards.